# why host process contains kubernetes pod process

Tags: kubernetes

when I am list process of host using this command:

```
[root@fat001 ~]# ps -o user,pid,pidns,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,args ax|grep "room"
root      3488 4026531836  0.0  0.0 107992   644 pts/11   S+   20:06:01 00:00:00 tail -n 200 -f /data/logs/soa-room/spring.log
root     18114 4026534329  8.5  2.2 5721560 370032 ?      Sl   23:17:51 00:01:53 java -jar /root/soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
root     19107 4026531836  0.0  0.0 107992   616 pts/8    S+   19:14:10 00:00:00 tail -f -n 200 /data/logs/soa-room/spring.log
root     23264 4026531836  0.0  0.0 112684  1000 pts/13   S+   23:39:57 00:00:00 grep --color=auto room
root     30416 4026531836  3.4  3.4 4122552 567232 ?      Sl   19:52:03 00:07:53 /opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5011 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/dump /data/jenkins/soa-room-service/soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am very sure this process is kubernetes pod's process:

```
root     18114 4026534329  8.5  2.2 5721560 370032 ?      Sl   23:17:51 00:01:53 java -jar /root/soa-room-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Why the kubernetes container's process show on host?It should be in the docker's container!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. **Containers are not VM.**

Every process run by Docker is run on the host Kernel. There is no isolation in term of *Kernel*.

Of course, there is an isolation in terms of process between containers, as each container's process are run in an isolated process namespace.

In summary : container A can't see container B process *(well, not by default)*, however as all the containers process are run inside your host, you'll always be able to see the process from your host.